# Poor layer adhesion on only one layer of PETG print

Tags: adhesion, petg, layer

One layer of PETG is not printing correctly

I’ve successfully been able to print in PETG, and it looks perfect except for a random layer in the middle of the print. It adheres to the bed fine, and the rest of the layers are fine, but one in the middle appears detached and weak. You can see the line in the plastic that goes all the way around. Any idea why?

This is the second time printing. I thought maybe there was a power issue or something while printing that caused it, but now I have the same effect again.

I have an Ender 3 Pro with a spider hotend and use Overture PETG. Nozzle at 255 °C and bed at 85 °C (initial layer is 260 °C and 90 °C), no fan, 90 mm/s speed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the gcode to make sure there aren't actually missing extrusions in that layer? Some versions of Cura have a bug where they'll omit large parts of a particular layer. If that's not the problem, look for anything different in that layer of the gcode preview that might be related (odd travels, etc.)

Comment: Nothing strange in the GCode